# How to review a complete feature branch before merging

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

How can I review changes in a feature branch / named branch, seeing all changes made in this branch?

I know I can review all individual commits one by one, but this leads to reviewing some code in one commit, which is the maybe modified or removed few commits later.

I also know about comparing any revisions of the repository (Visual Diff in TortoiseHg) and use this to compare last commit of the named branch with its starting point. This fails however, if the named branch was integrating changes from default in between.

Any other way?

Comment: Why not compare it to the branch you intend to merge into?

Comment: Because the difference will have both feature branch changes and destination branch (default typically) changes. But this could possibly work, if the destination branch would be integrated to the feature branch first. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have something like this:

```
             x + y   x + y + z
               |         |
   x       y   |    z    |     t
------|--------|---------|------------> default
       \        \         \
        \        \         \
         +--------+---------+---------> topic
             a    |    b    |    c    |
                  |         |          \
              x + a + y     |           x + a + y + b + z + c
                            |
                    x + a + y + b + z
```

To see only `a + b + c` you should compare the `P2` of the last merge with the `tip` of `topic`. The command you should use is `hg diff -r 'p2(last(merge())):.'`.

Below, there is a test case that corresponds to the previous diagram:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
hg init view-abc
cd view-abc
echo x > x
hg commit -Am x

hg branch topic
echo a > a
hg commit -Am a

hg up default
echo y > y
hg commit -Am y

hg up topic
hg merge default
hg commit -m merge
echo b > b
hg commit -Am b

hg up default
echo z > z
hg commit -Am z

hg up topic
hg merge default
hg commit -m merge

hg up default
echo t > t
hg commit -Am t

hg up topic
echo c > c
hg commit -Am c

hg diff -r 'p2(last(merge())):.'
```

Comment: It sounds like p2 is some mercurial function, but I cannot find details about it. Is this one of parents of this branch? Also, is there a possibility to make this in TortoiseHg or any other GUI? Mercurial solution is fine, but GUI solution would be a great bonus.

Comment: Yes, `p2()` gets the second parent. See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Merge. Also, please execute `hg help revsets` or visit https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets  for more information about `p2()` and other predicates.

Comment: You should enable the `extdiff` extension to call external programs (e.g. kdiff3) to compare revisions. Then, you run `hg extdiff -p kdiff3 -r 'p2(last(merge())):.'`.

Comment: I can't get it working. I figured out it is easy to search for revision in queries in TortoiseHg. However the query `p2(last(merge()))` doesn't seem to return a good result. `merge()` gives all merges ever done in any branch. `last(merge())` gives the last of them. In my case this is entirely different branch, as there are other feature branches in the repository as well.

Comment: This won't work in TortoiseHg because you are not selecting revisions but diff intervals. As I said previously, you should use `extdiff` extension and call `hg extdiff -p kdiff3 -r 'p2(last(merge())):.'` from the command line.

Comment: I'm very sorry but this does not work. I have tried `hg extdiff -p meld -r 'p2(last(merge())):.'` - it runs the tool but compares to a wrong parent. Also `hg log -r p2(last(merge()))` does not return the right parent to compare. Instead of returning 2nd parent of the last merge operation on the current branch (which I think is what you want), it returns 2nd parent of the last merge operation on *any* branch. It might work in example above because there is only one feature branch, but I have more branches - and it compares wrong things.

Comment: Additionally, while looking for some solution, I found some promising results using this query `last(p2(follow()))`. However it seems to fail, if the feature branch did not merge default to it at any point.

Comment: Are you running `hg diff -r 'p2(last(merge())):.'` from the tip of the topic branch you want? In the test case, the interval being compared is `hg log -r 5:8`. The first revision is 5. If you draw a schema of your scenario, I could tell.

Comment: Yes, I'm running from the tip of the feature branch. I'll try to make an example like you have, but this might be next week as I just go for holiday..